# Google Chat API onMessage trigger failing after configuration

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hangouts

I created with Apps Script (runtime V8) a Google Chat Bot, that has a backend action triggered by a card; the action is a simple `UrlFetchApp` call.

Because of this, the bot is not immediately able to respond and so, after a manual input from the user, the configuration card shows up in the user chat.

The problem is that straight after having provided all the authorizations to the pop-up, the `onMessage` trigger fails (see image below).

I tried in all ways to debug, but the only (odd) thing I found is that

- onMessage is called 3 times in a row;
- all these calls are failing, with an execution time of 0s (so I suspect the failure happens somewhere else, not due to the function's code);
- there is no log at all.

the dummy `onMessage` function I'm using to debug

```
function onMessage(object_event) {
  try{
    console.log(object_event);
  
    return {
      text:'some text here'
    }

  }catch(error){
    console.log(error)
  }
}
```

and here is the manifest

```
{
  "timeZone": "Europe/Bucharest",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request"],
  "runtimeVersion": "V8",
  "chat": {
    "addToSpaceFallbackMessage": "Hello!\nTo get started, please send me a message and then click on the \"Configure\" button that will appear"
  }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug?

[image: screenshot from the execution stackdriver]

Comment: What is content of the manifest (appscript.json)? What runtime is your script using?

Comment: @Rubén I updated the question with the manifest. Runtime V8. thank you.

Comment: Please provide the rest of a minimal code example to reproduce this. ATM it isn't possible without the "back-end action" calling UrlFetchApp.

Comment: @Aerials to reproduce the issue, you could use this template https://script.google.com/create?template=hangoutsChat , and place " UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/") " anywhere in one of the functions

Comment: I run into no issues after going through configuring, and messaging the bot. To test it out I used `console.log(UrlFetchApp.fetch("http://www.google.com/").getResponseCode())` in my `onMessage(e)` function. Then in my execution logs at https://script.google.com/home/executions I was able to verify response code 200.